# VBA Subroutine to fill formula down column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, autofill

I have a current Sub that organizes data certain way for me and even enters a formula within the first row of the worksheet, but I am running into the issue of wanting it to be able to adjust how far down to fill the formula based on an adjacent column's empty/not empty status.  For example, each time I run a report, I will get an unpredictable amount of returned records that will fill out rows in column A, however, since I want to extract strings from those returned records into different Columns, I have to enter formulas for each iteration within the next three columns (B, C, and D).  Is there a way to insert a line that will evaluate the number of rows in Column A that are not blank, and then fill out the formulas in Columns B, C, and D to that final row?  (I know that tables will do this automatically once information is entered in the first row, but for logistical reasons, I cannot use tables).

My current code that fills out the formula in Column B, Row 2 is:

```
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-1],FIND(""By:"",RC[-1])+3,22)"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula that you actually need is

```
=IF(A2="","",MID(A2,FIND("By:",A2)+3,22))
```

instead of

```
=MID(A2,FIND("By:",A2)+3,22) '"=MID(RC[-1],FIND(""By:"",RC[-1])+3,22)"
```

This checks if there is anything in cell `A` and then act "**accordingly**"

Also Excel allows you to enter formula in a range in **one go**. So if you want the formula to go into cells say, `A1:A10`, then you can use this

```
Range("A1:A10").Formula = "=IF(A2="","",MID(A2,FIND("By:",A2)+3,22))"
```

Now how do we determine that `10`? i.e the Last row. Simple

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change the name of the sheet as applicable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find Last Row in Col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("B2:B" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(A2="""","""",MID(A2,FIND(""By:"",A2)+3,22))"
    End With
End Sub
```

[More About How To Find Last Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to populate columns B:D based on Column A

```
Range("B2:D" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
    "=MID($A2,FIND(""By:"",$A2)+3,22)"
```